# Clear input field in Hybrid iOS app doesn't worked

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I have try to clear field using `webelemnt.clear()` method, but it's not working for ionic hybrid app
Now it's working as clear input field by clicking on delete button on native keyboard
But it's too slow to perform tests.

Comment: This is a forwarded comment for [@ElCaifan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10902396/el-caifan): 
He doesn't have enough reputation to add a comment so I forwarded the comment.

When you say "hybrid", do you mean your app opens a web view? If so, you'll need to switch context from native to the web view. You can see more about contexts here: [http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/context/set-context/]

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom method which performs ARROW_RIGHT and BACK_SPACE on the keyboard, and then use it where ever you need.
This is what worked for me in python.

```
def clear(self):
        """Clears the text if it's a text entry element."""
        text_length = self.get_attribute('value').__len__()
        text_length = text_length if text_length != 0 else self.text.__len__()
        if text_length != 0:
            # pylint: disable=unused-variable
            for i in range(text_length):
                self.send_keys(keys=Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
                self.send_keys(keys=Keys.BACK_SPACE)
```